# Could someone please explain how the boolean in this code works?

Tags: java, while-loop, boolean, conditional-statements

This question is more to understand a portion of code I am working with.  The "valid" boolean in line 1 becomes a condition for the while statement in line 2.  When you put a boolean in a while condition, does that automatically change the boolean?  I don't understand how if valid is initialized to false, it would ever become true outside of the while loop -unless there is something about it being in the while condition?  I'm including a portion of the code so you can see what is happening.  This is part of a fraction calculator I'm trying to understand.

Thanks for your help!

```
boolean valid = false;   
while (!valid) {
    System.out.println("Please enter a Fraction a/b or integer (a): ");
    firstFraction = scan.nextLine();
    valid = validFraction(firstFraction);
    if (valid) {
        int findSlash = firstFraction.indexOf("/");
        if (findSlash >= 0) {
            firstFractionNumerator = Integer.parseInt(firstFraction.substring(0, findSlash));
            firstFractionDenominator = Integer.parseInt(firstFraction.substring(findSlash + 1, firstFraction.length()));
        } 
        else {
            firstFractionNumerator = Integer.parseInt(firstFraction.substring(0, firstFraction.length()));
            firstFractionDenominator = 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Look forward two lines to `valid = validFraction(firstFraction);`

Comment: Exactly, firstFraction is a string type and you are giving that to boolean.

Comment: @PranavPatel code is not giving the string `firstFraction`  to boolean, it gives the result of validating that string which must be a boolean, should be OK.

Comment: It's poorly written. The `if` block should be after the loop, unconditionally.

Comment: Thank you all for the comments!  These have helped me look at this code from a different perspective.  I see now that the validFraction method is affecting how this while statement is affected.  Thanks again! :)

Answer (score 0):

Just think about it conceptually. The goal is to get a valid fraction. Before you've asked the user, you don't have any fraction, so it's not valid. Then you ask the user and it could be either valid or invalid. If it is valid, you can quit the loop because you've succeeded, if it is invalid, you need to ask them again so you need to loop again.

Consider this simple example. We will continue the loop if we make a random number between 6-10, and quit if we pick a number 0-5

```
boolean shouldContinue = true;

while(shouldContinue) {
    shouldContinue = new Random().nextInt(10) > 5;
}
```

Comment: Your explanation really helps and I appreciate the feedback.  Your walkthrough makes sense. I used the example code you provided and ran a few tests with it, and I think I'm starting to get what is happening with this while loop.  Because the "valid" boolean is initially set to false, the condition has to be set to true in order for the program to be able to run the while loop (otherwise it would skip past it).  In other words, for a while loop to work with a boolean value, the value has to be set to true.  Does that sound right?

Comment: Correct. for any `while (<boolean expression>) {...}` loop, the `<boolean expression>` must evaluate to true for the loop to continue. Also keep in mind that "not false" (`!false`) is a true.

Answer (score 0):

As per the code, it is not meant to be true outside the while loop. The concept of the loop is to work until it finds a valid firstFraction. In other words; code will keep asking for input until user gives valid one (valid per code rules in `validFraction` method).

Then it takes that valid input and processes it, what's in the `if (valid) {}` is irrelevant to the loop decision making and it's just for checking weather the input is a/b or an integer.
Then loop quits and code proceeds to what's implemented after the while loop.

In conclusion, the loop is good.

Comment: Makes much more sense! I was getting stuck on what was causing the while to work. The comment that user @jb. made about the while loop plus his code example made me wonder if for any while loop that uses a boolean condition, that boolean condition must be set to true in order for a while loop to work, and if it is set to false, the computer would skip past that while loop altogether.  Hopefully this observation is accurate -if I'm wrong, please correct me!  Your comment on the way the code answers the validFraction method to leave the loop answers the 2nd half of my question-thank you so much!